# Keep Bootstrap carousel menu always horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a modified version of the following carousel snippet:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/tabbed-slider-carousel

My problem is: When you make the screen smaller, the list elements change from horizontal to vertical. I would like to keep it always horizontal but I cant find the point to jump in to change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this part of code that keeps them horizontal:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
  .nav-justified>li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
}
```

You can apply this without the min-width but keep in mind that the contents should be very narrow to keep it responsive.

Comment: Okay thanks it worked! As you said I need to make this thing responsive now. I currently have six list elements and of course it becomes too much for small displays. Is there a way to group three elements per row so I end up with a 2x3grid?

Comment: You can try something like this: .nav-justified>li { display: block; float: left; width: calc(100% / 3); }